# Custom UITableViewCell drawn with CoreGraphics and threading issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, thread-safety, core-graphics

I'm using core graphics to draw a custom UITableViewCell, based on the Fast TableView sample from Loren Brichter.

I'm using some iVars in the custom cell class, that I'm creating as atomic (multithread safe) with a strong Reference (hence ARC).

Now the problems begin when I start scrolling the tableView too fast.
I get random crashes on the `- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)rect` method that I'm subclassing to perform the custom drawing.

The problem is that the iVars I'm using in the custom cell class, have been released and the memory is now owned by other objects, which of course leads to crashes.

I tried using the @synchronized directive to the whole draw code, to force a mutex lock on the drawing code, but this didn't solve the problem.

Did anyone else face this problem and knows a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atomic does not universally mean "multithread safe." It just means that the when you use the getter, then you will get an extra retain/autorelease pair on it (so it can't vanish during your runloop), and it'll be @synchronized with the setter, so that you can't get half-an-object if setting and getting collide. This is all only true if you use the getter and setters. You should not be accessing the ivars directly. If you are, then atomic means nothing.

You may also be modifying the main UIKit context on a thread other than the main thread. You can't do this. The main UIKit context (the one handed to `drawRect:`) is only valid on the main thread.

Comment: Rob, I'm drawing with GCD. I'm using a CALayer. I draw everything in a background thread then I'm getting the context as an image and set the layer content to that image in the main thread... Is that wrong? If yes, how should I do this correctly? And you say I shouldn't access the ivars my self. If not, how would I pass a text string from the uitableview class to the custom cell so I can draw it?

Comment: As long as the final `setContents:` is done on the main thread, then there's definitely no problem (you can generally call `[CALayer setContents:]` on any thread). Regarding accessing ivars, I mean you should not directly access the ivar (`foo`), even within the object. You should always go through the accessor (`self.foo`). The exceptions to this are in `init`, `dealloc`, and the accessors themselves.

Comment: Thank you Rob. It was the iVar accessing issue. I really didn't know that accessing them as foo vs self.foo had this difference. I'm also wondering why foo vs self.foo should point to a different memory location, as they are the same "object". Are you explaining this in your book?

Comment: Yes, chapter 3. The issue here is that when you call self.foo and foo is atomic, you're going to get an retained and autoreleased version of foo. So if someone calls setFoo: on another thread, your reference is still valid for the rest of the run loop. But if you use foo directly, then if someone calls setFoo:, you're can now be pointing to deallocated memory.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Rob. I have the book and will read it again more carefully, as I only read parts of it.